# Fatal error: Call to a member function asXML() on a non-object PHP

Tags: php

Tengo el siguiente problema, al querer ejecutar un archivo php, me tiene quedar una devolución, me muestra el siguiente error en pantalla:

```
 Fatal error: Call to a member function asXML() on a non-object
```

Este es mi código:

```
        function getXMLValue($stringXML, $tag)
    {
        return str_replace("</" . $tag . ">", "", str_replace("<" . $tag . ">", "", $stringXML));
    }

    $argv = array();
    $numero_tarjetaOK = $this->numero_tarjeta = str_replace(" ", "+", $this->getRequestParameter('nro_tarjeta'));

    $argv["identificador"] = $numero_tarjetaOK;
    $argv["Limite"] = 18;
    $argv["Offset"] = 0;

    $useAlternativeWebservice = true;

    if ($useAlternativeWebservice) {
        $WSrequest = '<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\" xmlns:dat=\"http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice\"> <soap:Header/> <soap:Body> <dat:buscar_novedades> <dat:identificador>' . $argv["identificador"] . '</dat:identificador> <dat:Limite>' . $argv["Limite"] . '</dat:Limite> <dat:Offset>' . $argv["Offset"] . '</dat:Offset> </dat:buscar_novedades> </soap:Body> </soap:Envelope>';

        $url = "https://11.12.13.14:8080/Boletines";

        $curl_str = "curl -k --url \"$url\" --data \"$WSrequest\"";
        $response = shell_exec($curl_str);

        #echo $WSrequest;

        #echo $response;

        $xmlresponse = simplexml_load_string($response);

        $datosNovedades = $xmlresponse->children('soap', true)->Body->children('ns0', true)->novedades->children('ns0', true);

        $var1 = str_replace("ns0:", "", $datosNovedades->novedad->identificador->asXML()); //->replace("ns0:","");
        $var2 = $datosNovedades->novedad->identificador->asXML();
        //echo "\n";
        //echo $datosNovedades->novedad->Fecha_Alta->asXML();

        //echo "\n";
        //echo "\n";
        $devolucion = parse_str(getXMLValue($var1, "identificador"));
        echo $devolucion;
        // echo "\n";
        // echo getXMLValue($var2,"ns0:identificador");

        //$this->WSrequest = $WSrequest;
    }
```

En teoria tendria que parsearlo, ya que el curl me devuelve un string, pero no logro hacerlo.

Desde ya muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Haz un `var_dump($datosNovedades);` y revisa si arroja un objeto válido y lo que hay en la ruta `->novedad->identificador->` de dicho objeto, pues el error dice que intentas aplicar `asXML` sobre un no-objeto, lo cual parece indicar que lo que hay en `$datosNovedades->novedad->identificador->` no es un objeto.

Comment: esta es la devolucion:                                           object(SimpleXMLElement)[69]
  public 'CodigoError' => string '999' (length=3)
  public 'MensajeError' => string 'Unknown operation' (length=17)
  public 'CodigoRespuesta' => string '999' (length=3)
  public 'MensajeRespuesta' => string 'Unknown operation' (length=17)

Comment: Como podrás ver en el resultado del `var_dump`, no se está creando un XML válido que contenga los nodos que esperas. Debes revisar con quien provee el XML a qué se debe ese error `999`. Si eres tú mismo el programador del servicio Soap entonces debes revisarlo.